# Reading Complex DATA in MATLAB from a File

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I want to read COMPLEX data present in a txt file into 1D array in MATLAB. I'm novice in MATLAB. Please help me out.

Excuse me for the ambiguous question. Sincere Apologies..

Actually I have a .txt file containing strings that represents complex numbers(Single line in .txt file represents ) for eg:

1+3i

i

-1-i

.

.

.

So on...

I want to read the same in **1 * N** Matrix (where **N** represents number of complex numbers in .txt file) in **MATLAB**. How I may do so?

Comment: what do you mean by complex? This is not how you describe your question.

Comment: m extremely sorry for the ambiguous question. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you have a text file with two columns, the real and imaginary parts. In which case, you can do this:

```
>> type cplx.txt % real and imaginary parts are two columns
1 2
3 4
5 6
>> rawData = dlmread('cplx.txt')

rawData =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6

>> complexData = complex(rawData(:, 1), rawData(:, 2))

complexData =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i
   3.0000 + 4.0000i
   5.0000 + 6.0000i
```

EDIT

Ok, with that file format, you should be able to use TEXTSCAN.

```
>> type cplx2.txt

1+3i
1i
2
4-4i
>> fid = fopen('cplx2.txt', 'rt');
>> x = textscan(fid, '%f');
>> fclose(fid);
>> x{1}

ans =

  1.000000000000000 + 3.000000000000000i
  0.000000000000000 + 1.000000000000000i
  2.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
  4.000000000000000 - 4.000000000000000i
```

Note that TEXTSCAN can't handle a line that consists of 'i' on its own. Which is a shame.

Comment: Thanks __Edric__ for ua help but the data in the .txt file is as described above in my modified question.

Comment: I just used textscan on a .txt file with a 27317x27317 complex matrix of format i.e. (-0.002572-0.009656j), it's giving me an empty cell.